# "No module name adafruit_servokit"

Tags: python-3.x, nvidia-jetson, servo, adafruit-circuitpython

I am working on Jetson Nano and trying to control servo motors. I am using PCA9685. I have installed all the pre-requisites for that

```
sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
```

Faced an error called

> SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined

i updated python for that and the issue was resolved. Now the issue is that when i use python 3.8 as an interpreter in Visual studio i face the error

> No module name adafruit_servokit

But when i use the python 3.6, the adafruit_servokit error is solved and the annotation error arises.
Looking forward to every suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have conflicting interpreters for your python installation.

Inside your Visual Studio terminal, try using:

```
python3.8 -m pip install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit
```

Using python -m pip install instead of just pip install is recommended. The reason is that it will use the correct interpreter for your python installation, specially if you have many versions installed. More details here: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

---EDIT---

You should replace `python3.8` with your target version number.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied. Still the same issue

Comment: try it with `python3.8 -m pip install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit`

Comment: Thank you, brother. The issue is solved. Really appreciate your help. Good day

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please mark the answer as solved. There is a check mark next to the answer. It can help others to solve the same issue.